# Saving the Learned Weights of a Network to Train on another Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I would like to train a MLP(Multi Layer Perceptron) with MNIST dataset. I use a validation set so I can save the weights of the best model. Then I want to load these weights back into the same architecture and use them to initialize and train with another dataset. I would like to know if this is possible with Tensorflow 1.x or 2.x. Right now I am trying to write a custom function to do it but it is getting complicated. I am using tf 1.x.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at tensorflow's documentation, here a link of a tutorial to save your weights and load them afterwards:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load